Binomial distribution given that zero's are rejected
Suppose I define a random process in which I repeatedly sample from a binomial distribution $X_k \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ until $X_k \neq 0$, at which point I set $Y = X_k$. What is $\mathbb{P}(Y = y)$?
I think I have derived the correct answer, but I need formalising/advice on whether my argument is valid.
We know that $Y$ cannot be zero and so the following formula is valid for $y \neq 0$.
$\mathbb{P}(Y = y) = \mathbb{P}(X_0 = y) + \mathbb{P}(X_1 = y)\mathbb{P}(X_0 = 0) + \mathbb{P}(X_2 = y)\mathbb{P}(X_0 = 0)^2 + \cdots$
Then this is an infinite geometric sum, hence
$\mathbb{P}(Y = y) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X = y)}{1 - \mathbb{P}(X = 0)}$
I'm not sure how to argue the first part of the argument. I tried using law of total expectation however it becomes self referential i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y = y | y \neq 0). $
I have run a monte-carlo experiment which agrees with my analytic derivation. Any help welcome!

The events $(X_0=y)$ and $(X_0=0, X_1=0,...X_{k-1}=0, X_k=y), k=1,2,\cdots$ are pairwise disjoint and their union is $(Y=y)$. Hence, $$\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\mathbb{P}(X_0=0)+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_0=0, X_1=0,...X_{k-1}=0, X_k=y)$$ $$=\mathbb{P}(X_0 = y) + \mathbb{P}(X_1 = y)\mathbb{P}(X_0 = 0) + \mathbb{P}(X_2 = y)\mathbb{P}(X_0 = 0)^2 + \cdots.$$

There is a hidden random variable $K$ here, which is the first $k$ such that $X_k\neq 0$.
Now if we work out $\mathbb{P}(Y=y\mid K=k)$, we get
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y=y\wedge K=k)}{\mathbb{P}(K=k)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_i=0\;\forall\;i<k)\mathbb P(X_k=y)}{\mathbb{P}(X_i=0\;\forall\;i<k)\mathbb P(X_k\neq 0)}=\frac{\mathbb P(X_k=y)}{\mathbb P(X_k\neq 0)}.$$
But this does not depend on $k$. Thus $Y$ and $K$ are independent and $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\mathbb P(X_0=y)/\mathbb P(X_0\neq 0)$.
